# Laravel how to initialize datepicker on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datepicker

I have a `laravel`-modal where I need the [jquery-datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to work, but for some reason the datepicker does not get initialized.

```
@push('modals')
 <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="uploadModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('application.store') }}">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <input name="birthyear" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="birthyear" required />
         </div>
       ...
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then, in my app.js I do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='birthyear']").datepicker({ format: "dd-mm-yyyy" });
});
```

But nothing happens!?! I've also tried by setting an ID but no difference.

Does someone have a clue?

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz No, not at all

Comment: @ST80 just make sure your script is included on that page. As in jsfiddle the same code is working. https://jsfiddle.net/urkx3osp/

Comment: sometimes it might be the cache issue... try in browser > inspect view > source includes your javascript changes.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you maybe misunderstood... The modal is a popup...

Comment: Yes I got that... just inspect the code and make sure, your model-popup code & Javascript code would be on same page after parsing in html.

Comment: Hopefully you have included the js in `layout` that being used or where @stack would be defined.

Comment: you are missing id="birthyear" in your modal form. your js file not well defined. see the updated answer i posted below.

Comment: @JuliusFasema code is running fine... seems js binding with element not there... https://jsfiddle.net/urkx3osp/

Comment: @VikashPathak i noticed, think its missing id attribute.

Comment: It was the missing `@yield('scripts')` what caused the issue! Thanks alot anyway for taking the time :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your view. i modified it by adding `id="birthyear"`

```
@push('modals')
 <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="uploadModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('application.store') }}">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <input name="birthyear" id="birthyear" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="birthyear" required />
         </div>
       ...
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

javascript code. i called bootstrap cdn for datepicker. i believe you must have `@yield('scripts')` in your headers files on your layout.

```
@section('scripts')
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

 //process date of birth
        $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#birthyear').datepicker({
                    format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
                });  

            });

        $('#birthyear').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,  
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
        }); 
@stop
```

Comment: It was the missing `@yield('scripts')` what caused the issue :-s